# Change Block Tracking settings not retained for a VM on VMWare 5.5

Tags: vmware-esx

I'm trying to enable Change Block Tracking as per [this VMWare KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031873) but the setting **ctkEnabled** is not being retained in the advanced options or being added to the vmx file.
The setting **scsi0:0.ctkEnabled** *is* being retained and I see a file **vmname-ctk.vmdk** in the datastore. 
I've verified that the vm doesn't have any snapshots but don't see any other suggestions in the KB (or google, of course.)

Edit:

The last comment on [this community post](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/478253). It's a slightly different circumstance, but suggests that there is an known bug editing these settings in the web-gui.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the end goal here? I've never had to modify this setting.

Comment: The goal is to enable CBT, which improves the performance of incremental backups.

Comment: Using which backup software suite?

Comment: Backup Exec 2012.

Comment: Are you actually having a problem? It sounds like you enabled it successfully.

Comment: No, it's not enabled. The setting is lost and when I review the status of CBT on the servers with powercli, it returns false.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/597896/change-block-tracking-settings-not-retained-for-a-vm-on-vmware-5-5

A known issue

Comment: @Tisha - You linked back to this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the prerequisites [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1020128)?

Also, can you explain at which stage the setting disappears, e.g.: immediately after configuring, Etc.?

Comment: Yes I did read that kb article. The setting disapears immediately after adding it. i.e. I add the row with the option name and value, and if you re-sort the list, the setting is already gone.  I have 30+ other servers which have the setting enabled (I'm not sure if it's the default or if Symantec RAWS sets it at install), and this one server is cloned from the same template as another server where it works.

Comment: Mmmm... If it were me, my next step would be to check the vmware.log file for one of the troublesome guests.  I know this log file is a nightmare to read, as it's so verbose, but it might give a clue.  i.e.: is the hypervisor somehow rejecting the setting, and removing it, or is vCenter being an a**e.  Finally, I'd be looking to log a call with VMware.  You do have support don't you? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One VM doesn't work, but many others do? This is really a troubleshooting exercise that we may not be able to help you with... Granted, I've never needed to do this as VMware's vSphere Data Protection adds this to the virtual machine configuration automatically.

You *could* just add the requisite lines to the offending VM's configuration file manually.

```
ctkEnabled = "TRUE"                               
scsi0:0.ctkEnabled = "true"
```

Things that help to know in general:

- Version of ESXi/build number (*because: [bugs, and most people don't keep their VMware updated](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6195/im-tired-of-answering-questions-with-upgrade-the-firmware-or-run-updates)*).
- Is this a vSphere cluster or standalone host?
- What is *different* about the VM causing the problem?
- Do you have any snapshots present on this VM?
- Are you using the .NET vSphere client? The vSphere Web Client?
- What is the version of the actual virtual machine? vmx-10, vmx-09, 8, 7?
- How did you enable this feature on the other VMs?

Comment: I thought about editing the config file, but that feels like a hack to me. And it does look like it's a (little) known bug; I edit the question to reflect that.